# Legacy Query Optimiser vs Pivotal Query Optimizer

Tags: optimization, greenplum

Hi I am new to Greenplum database. I got to know that the default optimizer is legacy and to activate Pivotal optimizer we should enable "set optimizer = on".

**I want to know about following:**

1. What is the main difference between these two optimizer's
2. For what type of queries we should enable Pivotal optimizer for better
   performance.

Answer (score 1):

Anuraag.

Setting optimizer to "on" enables a set of modifications to the original Postgres optimizer to better handle things like queries on very large partitioned tables, subqueries,  and CTE SQL (WITH statements).   There are other ongoing modifications to make the optimizer code more modular and more efficient on all types of SQL queries, but that is where the focus was originally.   I am not on the optimizer team (Pivotal Data Field engineer here) so there are probably others who can give you more in depth answers on this topic than I can.

As far as which queries benefit most, the best answer would be: "it depends" :).  Generally, very large partitioned table queries will be handled more efficiently and faster with optimizer = on.  Same with CTE queries and queries with sub-selects in them.   I have also seen some more standard star schema-type queries run faster with optimizer = on.

In either case, the optimizer depends on very good statistics in the database, so you need to make sure ANALYZE is run after large loads or deletes/truncates.

Your best bet is to run and time your queries with optimizer on and off (it can be set at the session level).   The size of your dataset and your database schema structure may show generally faster times with optimizer either on or off, so I would go with whichever setting works best for your particular situation.   I work with a lot of Greenplum customers.  Some have optimizer set to default on, some set to off.   Find the default setting that works best for the bulk of your queries, and use the opposite setting in cases where a query is running "slowly" and see if you get better results.

I hope this answers your question.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

For partitioned table, make sure you run analyze root partition since PQO uses stats on the root partition and not the leaf partitions like Planner.